# How can I get the Terminus font on gnome-terminator?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, terminal, fonts, gnome-terminator

I'm trying to get the Terminus font on Terminator, and I already did the following:

- Got the fonts in the right place I think:

  ```
  └─▪  tree -a .local/share/fonts/                                                                                                                                                          
  .local/share/fonts/                                                                                                                                                                       
  ├── Hack                                                                                                                                                                                  
  │   ├── Hack-BoldOblique.otf                                                                                                                                                              
  │   ├── Hack-Bold.otf                                                                                                                                                                     
  │   ├── Hack-RegularOblique.otf                                                                                                                                                           
  │   └── Hack-Regular.otf                                                                                                                                                                  
  ├── Inconsolata                                                                                                                                                                           
  │   └── Inconsolata.otf                                                                                                                                                                   
  ├── SourceSansPro                                                                                                                                                                         
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-BlackIt.otf                                                                                                                                                         
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-Black.otf                                                                                                                                                           
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-BoldIt.otf                                                                                                                                                          
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-Bold.otf                                                                                                                                                            
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt.otf                                                                                                                                                    
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.otf                                                                                                                                                      
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-It.otf                                                                                                                                                              
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-LightIt.otf                                                                                                                                                         
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-Light.otf                                                                                                                                                           
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-Regular.otf                                                                                                                                                         
  │   ├── SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt.otf                                                                                                                                                      
  │   └── SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf                                                                                                                                                        
  └── Terminus                                                                                                                                                                              
      ├── terminus-12.pcf                                                                                                                                                                   
      ├── terminus-14-bold.pcf                                                                                                                                                              
      ├── terminus-14.pcf                                                                                                                                                                   
      ├── terminus-16-bold.pcf                                                                                                                                                              
      ├── terminus-16.pcf                                                                                                                                                                   
      ├── terminus-18-bold.pcf                                                                                                                                                              
      ├── terminus-18.pcf                                                                                                                                                                   
      ├── terminus-20-bold.pcf                                                                                                                                                              
      └── terminus-20.pcf                                                                                                                                                                   

  4 directories, 26 files
  ```
- Did the right fc-cache updates, see here:

  ```
  └─▪ sudo fc-cache -fv       
  /usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 4 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1: caching, new cache contents: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc: caching, new cache contents: 59 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/util: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 5 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-cns1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-gb1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-japan2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/cmap/adobe-korea1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 22 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/abyssinica: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid: caching, new cache contents: 18 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst: caching, new cache contents: 15 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/kacst-one: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/lao: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 16 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/nanum: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto: caching, new cache contents: 48 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/openoffice: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/padauk: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/sinhala: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/takao-gothic: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/tibetan-machine: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/tlwg: caching, new cache contents: 54 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu: caching, new cache contents: 21 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core: caching, new cache contents: 17 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-khmeros-core: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-punjabi-fonts: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family: caching, new cache contents: 13 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy: caching, new cache contents: 2 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/type1: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/share/fonts/type1/mathml: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Hack: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Inconsolata: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/SourceSansPro: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Terminus: caching, new cache contents: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
  /usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 4 dirs
  /usr/local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
  /home/me/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
  /var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
  /home/me/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
  /home/me/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
  fc-cache: succeeded
  ```

  and here:

  ```
  └─▪ sudo fc-cache -fv .local/
  /home/me/.local: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 13 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 7 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Borat...(2006) & Bruno (2009) 720p multi [mkvonly]: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras/Artwork: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras/eXtraS: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 3 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras/eXtraS/A. Trailers!: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras/eXtraS/C. Opening and Ending Songs: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Death Note (English Dubbed) TV Complete + Extras/eXtraS/Z. Videos to Watch After Completing the Series: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/Udemy - How I Make a Website in Wordpress that sell for $100-$1000!: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/_PLEASE SUPPORT_: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/_PLEASE SUPPORT_.2: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/_PLEASE SUPPORT_.3: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/muz: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/Trash/info: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/applications: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/cinnamon: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/cinnamon/applets: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/cinnamon/desklets: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/cinnamon/search_providers: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 4 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Hack: caching, new cache contents: 4 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Inconsolata: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/SourceSansPro: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/fonts/Terminus: caching, new cache contents: 9 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/gvfs-metadata: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/icc: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/keyrings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/mime: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/mime/packages: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/mime/video: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/nemo: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 2 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/nemo/actions: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/nemo/scripts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/tomboy: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/totem: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/vlc: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/webkitgtk: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
  /home/me/.local/share/webkitgtk/localstorage: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
  /home/me/.local: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
  /var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
  /home/me/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
  /home/me/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
  fc-cache: succeeded
  ```
- I'm currently running Mint, so I decided to follow this protip - http://chrisacheson.net/blog/2009/03/21/how-to-get-profont-working-in-ubuntu/ and adjusted my ~/.fonts.conf:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">                                                                                                                             
    <fontconfig>                                                                                                                                                                              
     <selectfont>                                                                                                                                                                             
      <acceptfont>                                                                                                                                                                            
       <pattern>                                                                                                                                                                              
        <patelt name="family"><string>ProFont</string></patelt>                                                                                                                               
        <patelt name="family"><string>Terminus</string></patelt>                                                                                                                              
       </pattern>                                                                                                                                                                             
      </acceptfont>                                                                                                                                                                           
     </selectfont>                                                                                                                                                                            
    </fontconfig>
```

And still I can't select the font in Terminator's preferences.

The font works on Terminology however.

I'm currently running Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64bit

---

**Edit:**

After the suggestion of @Peter, I did `dpkg -L xfonts-terminus` and [here's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4s2LQ2Jb) the result

So it looks like it's installing it in much more places than I though initially. Note that the font is not called terminus but rather an abbreviation (`/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u12b_koi8-r.pcf.gz`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just `apt-get install xfonts-terminus` ?

The Terminus fonts are already available pre-packaged for Mint, see [xfonts-terminus](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xfonts-terminus)

Comment: That worked, thanks! Optionally I'd like to know a method of getting that font working independent of Ubuntu derived distros, but then I guess one of those aforementioned methods might work out.

Comment: @AppAraat you could try dpkg -L xfonts-terminus to see if it placed the files somewhere else you didn't expect.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I added the result of your suggestion. It seems that there were a lot of places I did not expect :)